# Error while converting XML response to Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

Goal is to convert XML response to JSON. I am hitting an API endpoint which returns XML data. I recieve the data, convert it to json string but when i try to deserialize the json string, it throws exception that

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: :. Path '', line 1, position 6

```
public string GetSaveData(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var response = client.DownloadString(url);
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(response);
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
                var transactObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); **//Exception is thrown at this line**
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return "success";
    }
```

Exception is thrown at transactObject1.

Comment: So have you been able to reproduce this locally with a console application that just loads a local XML file, so you can show us the XML file, and also the JSON that `SerializeXmlNode` returns? Basically, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi -- can you tell us what your `json` looks like immediately after `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode...`

Comment: I have tested it with small amout of hardcoded xml  data. it didnt threw exception. But when i use data returned from API it throws exception.

Comment: the data is huge, cannot paste here

Comment: "the data is huge, cannot paste here" - so reduce it to a small amount of hardcoded XML data that *does* show the problem. Take your huge amount of data, and see whether "just the first half" shows the problem. If it does, get rid of the second half. If it doesn't, see if "just the second half" shows the problem. If it does, get rid of the first half. (If it doesn't, things get trickier, of course.) Repeat until you have a small example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You may not be getting xml response.  See similar issue recently and found JSON was being returned.  Had to change http request headers to get xml.  It was unusual from a webpage I got xml but httpwebrequest with same URL got JSON.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddle to check response and also check to see if status is 200 OK,

Comment: i am able to solve it by removing the XML declaration tag at the very start of XML document. Which was making the entire doc to be not correctly parsed.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution by removing the starting tag that declares the XML document which was causing the json string to be malformed.

```
 public string GetSaveData(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var response = client.DownloadString(url);
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(response);
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc)
                {
                    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                    {
                        doc.RemoveChild(node);
                    }
                }
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
                var transactObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return "success";
    }
```